# Block /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf from non root users but still allow all users to connect to that ssid

Tags: permissions

How do i block `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` from non root users but still allow all users to connect to that ssid? For example if I have a hidden network called `xyz` with password `1234secure`. I connect to that ssid from the admin account. After i logout, i want the demo user called `demo` to be able to login and connect to that access point without being able to `vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to see the password. Right now creating a new user that is not in the sudoers group can view that file because by default it is `rw,r,r`. If i change it to `rw,-,-` i don't know how the system will read it.

Comment: Are you looking at the one in /boot when you set it up at install time?  `cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as Pi returns **Permission denied**

Comment: `vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` opens up for the other user and permissions are `rw,r,r`. The data in there is what was setup during initial install wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default permissions are:-

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1055 2021-03-05 11:14 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

There is no problem unless you (or some program) fiddled with it.

Comment: i'm not sure why mine is different. It's a fresh install with no additional packages added. Reading Andrews comment i wonder if that file's permissions starts out `rw,r,r` during the initial install and is changed the next time the wifi is modified. I don't have any other ideas other than the sd card with pi preinstalled might not be authentic.

Comment: @learnsomemore I doubt the "file's permissions starts out rw,r,r" - it never has in my experience. I haven't used this in years - I put my `wpa_supplicant.conf` which is copied on boot and the correct permission set. I use `wpa_passphrase` so even root can't read the password.

Answer (score 1):

Awhile ago, I downloaded a clean version of Buster (with desktop) for ethernet connection and can see the following:

I had added ssh to /boot and booted up directly on the hardwired network - this **does** give Pi access to wpa_supplicant.conf as it has the rights:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 83 Dec 27 16:44 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

BUT it obviously does not contain any WiFi details at this point.

Trying to create a wpa_supplicant using `nano /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` returns **Error writing /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf: Permission denied** when trying to save the file as /boot has the *drwxr-xr-x* permission.

Using `sudo nano /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` creates the file as

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 151 Mar  5 13:51 /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Doing a reboot connects to my WiFi and Ethernet networks and the O/S start up moves the file out of /boot to /etc/wpa_supplicant and the resulting file in is secure:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 151 Mar  5 13:51 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

So it looks like on the standard version issued by RPF, the security settings are set fine.  What I should have done is spend a bit of time hunting around as it seems that this is handled by the **raspberrypi-net-mods.service** (as of this post) and this contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy user wpa_supplicant.conf
ConditionPathExists=/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf
Before=dhcpcd.service
After=systemd-rfkill.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/mv /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wifi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note the chmod after the move.  This will stop none root users from accessing the network (assuming you do not give sudo rights to any editors) and by default /boot is set to stop limited users adding new network info.